# Awk removing the line matching a string

Tags: awk

I am writing a script to remove the lines containing the repeated string. For example:

```
Epoch Time: 1418027874.795328000 seconds
Data: 4f67675300020000000000000000a6e0d
Epoch Time: 1418027874.807941000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000040caa20641080000a6e
Epoch Time: 1418027874.968753000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa20641080000a6e0d4e40
Epoch Time: 1418027875.131557000 seconds
Epoch Time: 1418027875.131557012 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa206410870000a6e0d4e40
```

I want to remove the instance of another epoch time that repeats twice on line 7.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Avinash Raj                                                                                            Epoch Time: 1418027874.795328000 seconds
Data: 4f67675300020000000000000000a6e0d
Epoch Time: 1418027874.807941000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000040caa20641080000a6e
Epoch Time: 1418027874.968753000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa20641080000a6e0d4e40
Epoch Time: 1418027875.131557012 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa206410870000a6e0d4e40

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you expect ?

```
$ awk -F'[ .]' '!epochs[$3]++' file
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Epoch Time: 1418027874.795328000 seconds
Data: 4f67675300020000000000000000a6e0d
Epoch Time: 1418027875.131557000 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had equal epochs in your data file (and you've not) the following would do it nicely

```
awk 'NF==4{if($3 in e)next;e[$3]} 1' your.data
```

#### Testing

```
% cat ep.dat
Epoch Time: 1418027874.795328000 seconds
Data: 4f67675300020000000000000000a6e0d
Epoch Time: 1418027874.807941000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000040caa20641080000a6e
Epoch Time: 1418027874.968753000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa20641080000a6e0d4e40
Epoch Time: 1418027875.131557000 seconds
Epoch Time: 1418027875.131557000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa206410870000a6e0d4e40
% gawk 'NF==4{if($3 in e)next;e[$3]}1' ep.dat
Epoch Time: 1418027874.795328000 seconds
Data: 4f67675300020000000000000000a6e0d
Epoch Time: 1418027874.807941000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000040caa20641080000a6e
Epoch Time: 1418027874.968753000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa20641080000a6e0d4e40
Epoch Time: 1418027875.131557000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa206410870000a6e0d4e40
% mawk 'NF==4{if($3 in e)next;e[$3]}1' ep.dat
Epoch Time: 1418027874.795328000 seconds
Data: 4f67675300020000000000000000a6e0d
Epoch Time: 1418027874.807941000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000040caa20641080000a6e
Epoch Time: 1418027874.968753000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa20641080000a6e0d4e40
Epoch Time: 1418027875.131557000 seconds
Data: 4f676753000080caa206410870000a6e0d4e40
%
```

NB I have edited the data file to have two equal epoch times

Comment: If I have understood the original question, my code works as per the example I've added to my answer.  OTOH, if I have misunderstood the original question, or maybe if our understandings differ...

Comment: I think he wants to remove one of the 2 "Epoch" lines if multiple of them appear before a "Data" line. I don't think he only wants to remove them when the time is identical. I don't know if he wants to remove the first or the last one, though. All just guesswork without the expected output of course...

Comment: Thank you for the comments. As Ed Morton mentioned, I would like to remove the first line in Epoch time because the Epoch does not correspond to Data (in my case). I want to keep the second line.